# Grails spring security: how to undo s2-quickstart

Tags: grails, spring-security

Every time I do s2-quickstart I mess something up and have to delete my project from STS and my hard drive and then make it from scratch because I can't understand what is broken.  Then I do s2-quickstart again on that project and possibly delete it and start over if I messed up again.  Is there some way to undo what has been done with s2-quickstart so I can just go reissue the s2-quickstart command correctly without deleting and retyping/pasting my project?

Comment: use tools like `git`. And rollback whenever you want ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what problems have you been having with it? Are you just mistyping what you wanted your User and Role classes to be named?

Comment: Yeah just mistyping.  Also, I do use git, but I forget to commit every time it would actually be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Spring Security Core Plugin - Reference Documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/1%20Introduction%20to%20the%20Spring%20Security%20Plugin.html#1.1%20Configuration%20Settings%20Now%20in%20Config.groovy):

The `s2-quickstart <package> <user> <role> <requestmap>` creates the following artefacts:

- Creates domain classes:

  - grails-app/domain/*package*/*user*.groovy
  - grails-app/domain/*package*/*role*.groovy
  - grails-app/domain/*package*/*userrole*.groovy
  - grails-app/domain/*package*/*requestmap*.groovy (if specified)
- Creates example GSPs and controllers:

  - grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp
  - grails-app/views/login/denied.gsp
  - grails-app/controllers/LoginController.groovy
  - grails-app/controllers/LogoutController.groovy
- Adds configuration to Config.groovy:

  - grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = '*package*.*user*'
  - grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = '*package*.*userrole*'
  - grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = '*package*.*role*'

You should be able to delete the artefacts and Config.groovy changes and run `s2-quickstart` again to start over.

Comment: @WillBuck You should move the comment up to the question itself as it's not really a comment about the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you use source control like `git`, as suggested by Ant's 
Here is a quick start tut http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch01.html

Comment: Already on it, but I can never remember to commit before I do dangerous things.

Comment: :) it will come in time. after spending lots of time undoing stuff, i realized the value of source control